# Create table without drop if its exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, truncate

I need sone help in PL/SQl.

So my problem is, the following problem:

There is a table called: temp_table and I need to create a temp_table without drop/truncate option. It needs because all the time a table's data changing. 
So I know its weird, but this is necessary for my daily job.

The script work like this:
The script does a text import to table, and the table is given. It use a dblink to connect the database. It works, but all the time I have to use DROP. But I need  ( if its possible) to create an existing table without drop/truncate.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Sorry for no sql code, but i think it doesn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid that your question isn't clear.  If you want to create a table, you use `CREATE TABLE` though it basically never makes sense to create objects in Oracle at runtime.  You could query `dba_|all_|user_tables` to determine whether the table exists and only create it if it doesn't already exist.  But that would, at best, only make sense in an installation script.  I'm hard pressed to imagine what "creating an existing table" would do.

Comment: Show us the stored procedure you have.

Comment: At least add the table structure and data in your question.

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the concept you want is the external table. With external tables the data resides in OS files, such as CSVs.  This allows us to swap data sets without dropping the table.

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011).

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to drop the table because you want to reload it, but you also want there to be as close to constant up-time as possible?

I would create two temp tables.  You already have one called:

```
temp_table
```

Create another called:

```
temp_table_new
```

Load your new data into temp_table_new, then run a rename on it like so:

```
RENAME TABLE temp_table TO temp_table_old
 temp_table_new TO temp_table
```

Then

```
drop table temp_table_old
```

This will be super fast, have very little downtime, and allow you to have the functionality you've described.

Comment: Thanks for help, after many hour of search i found that the external table will solve my problem, but what you wrote is very usefull, thanks a lot.